# Conduit for Outside AC\Heatpump

Tags: wiring, hvac, air-conditioning, conduit, heat-pump

Need to run conduit for a new AC\heatpump. Main panel is in the garage. Looking to go through the wall to outside pretty much right at the panel and run it all on the side of the house. Outside the run is 30-40 Ft. I know I need a disconnect at the outside unit.

Can the conduit connect right to a knock out on the side of the main panel (Follow NEC here).
What types of conduit are acceptable? UV shouldn't be an issue, have 2 ft overhangs and looking to put it up at the top of the wall.

Answer (score 1):

Conduit can be (at least) any of PVC, EMT, IMC, RMC. LFNC if you are a masochist and want to waste money as well as making the job harder for yourself.

Below 8 ft outside PVC needs to be schedule 80 as being "exposed to damage" PVC electrical conduit is sunlight resistant.

Yes, conduit frequently connects right to a panel.

The run must be constructed in such a way that the wire can be pulled after the conduit is run, and there must be no more than 360 degrees of turns between access points for pulling (the box at each end, and any LB, LL, LR, *etcetera* conduit bodies with access plates.) Corners other than those made with LB, *etcetera*, need to be "sweeps" that can be pulled through.

360 degrees is "code maximum" - 270 or less is more friendly to you, the person pulling the wire. Likewise, 40% fill is the maximum, and somewhere down around 25% or less is easier to pull. Stranded wire pulls easier than solid wire.

Comment: Thanks for the info, I think I will have 270 degrees (3 90's). does it matter either way if the wire is sheathed in the conduit. I have a large roll of 2\1 12 Ga. already. Is this fine to use 2 wire like a water heater?

Comment: Normally in conduit you use **individual wires**, not cables of 2 or more wires. Typically that is either 2, 3 or 4 wires, depending on: 120 vs. 240 vs. 120/240 - your AC may need just 240 (2 hots) or it might need 120/240 (2 hots + 1 neutral). Plus may need ground. Always need to have ground, but with the right type of metal conduit, the metal conduit **is** the ground, saving a separate wire. Ground = green or bare, Neutral = white or gray, Hot = any other color (black, red, blue, yellow, etc.). The 2 hots can be the same color.

Comment: All outside conduit is defined as (and usually fits the definition) a wet location. Condensation will get the water in if no other way does. As such, your large roll of (probably interior, non-wet rated) cable is not a factor, without even getting into how unsuitable it is. If it IS wet rated cable (such as UF) it requires HUGE conduit .vs. the individual wires you need, since it is treated as a round cable of the largest diameter of the oval for fill purposes. You want THWN, or some other wire type marked with a W. You can't strip jacketed cable to get wires, they are not marked...

Comment: Does flex conduit gt included in the 360 degrees? say I use flex conduit from the disconnect to the unit that has a bend in it, does that count toward it?

Comment: Flex conduit not only counts, it's also by far the most miserable <bleep> to pull through, so it counts extra in my book. But since it's "from the disconnect to the unit" (both of which are access points for pulling) you could have 360 degrees per code in that section (but I'd really recommend not.) Only the bend in the flex would count towards the limit for the flex section, and has no impact on the rigid conduit sections past the access point (disconnect box.) The 360 degree restriction is between access points, not for the entire run.

Comment: @Ecnerwal Thanks, excited to get this bad boy going. Currently heating gets close to $400/month in the winter. One final question. Can this Use a standard breaker, my inspector told me about my water heater that it did not need afci/gfci. Would that be the same for this. Going to be 2 wires plus ground on a 30A breaker same as my water heater.